# CS50 library problems

Tags: c, visual-studio, clang, cs50

I'm learning C — I wanted to learn a "lower level language" and figured I'd give C a try. I'm running into problems with the CS50 library on my vs code

My code is as follows

```c
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    string s = get_string("Input: ");
    printf("Output: %s\n", s);
}
```

and then I get this message

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_get_string", referenced from:
      _main in fileone-18f2ad.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [fileone] Error 1
```

Comment: You need to link the CS50 library with your program. See the CS50 instructions for getting started.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I did, even followed a youtube video and I still get that same error message in the terminal when i try to run it

Comment: Are you running in the cloud version of vs code for the cs50?

Comment: You need to show the command you used to invoke the compiler.